# Where to find the explanations/purposes of opengl functions listed in developer.android.com?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I strat to learn OpenGL in Android. In developer.android.com I can see some example projects. In those examples, lot of OpenGL funcitons are used. But they doesn't explain why they are called? For example, in below snipet you can see the string variables declared with some coding kind of text. But in the entire guidance materials, I couldn't find why this text (especially this) is used?

```
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = vPosition;" +
        "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";
```

Also in the following snipet, there is some procedure kind of coding is followed. But nowhere I can find the procedures explained to follow.

```
public class Triangle() {
    ...

    private final int mProgram;

    public Triangle() {
        ...

        int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                                        vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                                        fragmentShaderCode);

        // create empty OpenGL ES Program
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

        // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

        // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

        // creates OpenGL ES program executables
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
    }
}
```

I know this developer.android.com guidelines are meant for android development. So If I try finding explanation for `glAttachShader()` or `glMatrixMode()` functions in class explanations available in the documentation, I am so surprised about what they gave. Have a look at it.

`glAttachShader`:

added in API level 8

```
void glAttachShader (int program, int shader)
```

Parameters

- `program` `int`
- `shader`  `int`

`glMatrixMode`:

added in API level 4

void glMatrixMode (int mode)

Parameters

- `mode`    `int`

Where are the explanations?? I couldn't interpret any of them.
Or is there any site or material to understand the purpose of each functions **JUST LISTED IN DEVELOPER DOCUMENTATION?**

Please help me and direct me to right material to learn Android OpenGL? I cannot play with the code (means) cannot take single step further other than the example project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where are the explanations??

In the OpenGL specification. OpenGL is not an invention of Google/Android and hence it makes sense that they will only document in what way to access the stuff that has been defined by a consortium of graphics vendors.

The authorative documentation can be found at https://www.opengl.org/documentation/

However to understand what's really going on you should follow a tutorial like the (official) Programming Guide (aka the Red Book) [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321773039/khongrou-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773039)

Or one of the inofficial tutorials like the *excellent* work of StackOverflow user @NicolBolas, which I've mirrored at http://opengl.datenwolf.net/gltut/html/index.html . Or you go with http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

Comment: OpenGL is similar, but not the same as OpenGL ES, so for mobile you probably want: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php for the specs, and http://www.opengles-book.com/es2/index.html or http://www.opengles-book.com/ for a guide.